# I have a excel table with list of numbers, I want to take one value from Browse screen and pass to another screen where it should be stored in field

Tags: powerapps

I have two excel tables where first one is basically list of orders and the second is list of order details. I need to pick order from first table and pass it to the second and store in field called OrderID - then on the screen build on the second table I need to complement screen with additional information and save. so far I was able to call another screen with Navigate function

Select(Parent); NewForm(EditForm1); Navigate(EditForm1, ScreenTransition.None,{selectedId: Zlecenia_Screen})

so far I was able to call another screen with Navigate function

Select(Parent); NewForm(EditForm1); Navigate(EditForm1, ScreenTransition.None,{selectedId: Zlecenia_Screen})

that allows me to go to EditForm1 but then it goes immediatelly to DetailScreen1

Comment: to sort this out, you should first use the Monitor functionality in Power Apps studio and figure out what causes your app to navigate to DetailScreen1. With Monitor you can trace back almost any logic that is being executed.